# How to use Django for effective geolocation?

Tags: python, iphone, django, geolocation

I want to do the following.

I want to create an app that does the following

- Restaurants put in the address where they are located.
- Person A opens up the app and sees the number of miles each restaurant is from his/her present location sorted by nearest.

How can I do this in the most effective way?

If the restaurant gives me their address, should I be converting that address to longitude/latitude points, and then somehow using that to get the distance from the person A current location? But how do I do this so effectively so that if there are 1000 addresses in the database, I can efficiently sort all of these addresses - nearest to person A first- without taking too much time? Thanks!

I am using django.

Comment: I'd like to do something similar. Were you able to find a good solution and do you have any example code you could share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/) and [PostGIS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/).

GeoDjango will give you the ability to store geo informations and do [distance lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-lookups).

You also could use [OSMGeoAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#osmgeoadmin) or [django-location-field](https://github.com/codasus/django-location-field) to help you easily fill the location fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Cloudmade's Geocoding API](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/geocoding-http-api) to locate the restaurant from the provided address.

And then you use [Cloudmade's Routing API](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/routing-http-api) to find the distances.

Comment: But how do I find the person's exact location?

Comment: Isn't that information coming from the person's GPS device inside their phone?